# How do I retrieve the Alpha Channel from an image in PHP?

Tags: php, graphics, image-manipulation

How do I retrieve the Alpha Channel from an image using PHP?

Answer (score 3):

By [`Imagick::getImageAlphaChannel()`](http://lt.php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-getimagealphachannel.php)

(Answer quality about as poor as question. Or maybe better - it has a link to the manual)

Comment: I lol'd. Note that GD can save Alpha detail, but can't really manipulate it as a channel.

Comment: Thank you. How can get "bit depth" from an image in PHP, not using Imagick.

Comment: That's a whole new question, which could probably be anserwed by [`getimagesize()` returned `bits` value](http://lt.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)

Comment: I also tried getimagesize() which gives you a "bits" value, but it was always 8 for image 8, 24, 32 bit depth.